# Data layer for Azure Mobile App

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-mobile-services

We have ASP.NET MVC5 application. We have used entity framework DB first approach for the data layer. Now we are planning to build Xamarin mobile app.

I'm looking for the options for developing back-end of the app. In Azure Mobile app it seems you have to derive your entity from EntityData. Also I read somewhere that DB first approach is not supported.

Do I need to create each entities for my existing table manually (code first)? It would be great if someone can help in guiding to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Doing DB first is harder, but not impossible.  I'd recommend reading my chapter on data https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/dataconcepts/ - there is a section that deals with DB first explicitly.